# Issues with enabling sbt-scapegoat plugin in a project that does not uses build.sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a project which does not have a build.sbt, instead there is a BuildSettings.scala file. 
I am trying to enable the scapegoat plugin in there and facing issues while doing so. 
Here is what I have done so far :

I added the addSbtPlugin("com.sksamuel.scapegoat" %% "sbt-scapegoat" % "1.0.4") to project/plugins.sbt file. Then tried building the project. it built successfully but when I try running scapegoat it gives following error

```
[error] Not a valid command: scapegoat (similar: set)
[error] Not a valid project ID: scapegoat
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: scapegoat (similar: aggregate)
[error] scapegoat
[error]          ^
```

Then I tried adding the scapegoatVersion to BuildSettings.scala file and that gave me compile time error

```
project\BuildSettings.scala:29: not found: value scapegoatVersion
[error]     scapegoatVersion      :=  "1.0.4",
[error]     ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

Then I added scapegoat as import to the BuildSettings.scala file, thinking that was missing. The error changes again

```
[error] bad symbolic reference. A signature in ScapegoatSbtPlugin.class refers to type AutoPlugin
[error] in package sbt which is not available.
[error] It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on
[error] the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling ScapegoatSbtPlugin.class.
[error] project\BuildSettings.scala:29: not found: value scapegoatVersion
[error]     scapegoatVersion      :=  "1.0.4",
[error]     ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

What might I be missing here? Please suggest some way/steps to enable this plugin properly for my project.

Thanks

Comment: [You need to use sbt 0.13.5+ to use this plugin](https://github.com/sksamuel/sbt-scapegoat#how-to-use). The bad symbolic error is due to the old version of sbt that you're using, which didn't have `AutoPlugin`s.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that. It resolved the error. The sbt version was 13.2.